# Matplotlib / python clickable points

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have a bunch of time series data with points every 5 seconds. So, I can create a line plot and even smooth the data to have a smoother plot. The question is, is there any way in matplotlib or anything in python that will allow me to click on a valid point to do something? So, for example, I would be able to click on (10, 75) if that datum exists in my original data and then I would be able to do something in Python.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: yes, see the picker demos

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To expand on what @tcaswell said, see the documentation here: http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html

However, you might find a quick demo of pick events useful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_pick(event):
    artist = event.artist
    xmouse, ymouse = event.mouseevent.xdata, event.mouseevent.ydata
    x, y = artist.get_xdata(), artist.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    print 'Artist picked:', event.artist
    print '{} vertices picked'.format(len(ind))
    print 'Pick between vertices {} and {}'.format(min(ind), max(ind)+1)
    print 'x, y of mouse: {:.2f},{:.2f}'.format(xmouse, ymouse)
    print 'Data point:', x[ind[0]], y[ind[0]]
    print

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

tolerance = 10 # points
ax.plot(range(10), 'ro-', picker=tolerance)

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)

plt.show()
```

Exactly how you approach this will depend on what artist you're using (In other words, did you use `ax.plot` vs. `ax.scatter` vs. `ax.imshow`?).

Pick events will have different attributes depending on the artist selected.  There will always be `event.artist` and `event.mouseevent`.  Most artists that have individual elements (e.g. `Line2D`s, `Collections`, etc) will have a list of the index of the items selected as `event.ind`.

If you'd like to draw a polygon and select points inside, see: http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/lasso_demo.html#event-handling-example-code-lasso-demo-py

Answer (score 4):

If in case you want to bind extra property to your artist object, for example you are plotting IMDB ratings of several movies, and you want to see by clicking on a point which movie it corresponds to, you can do that by adding a custom object to the point that you plotted, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class custom_objects_to_plot:
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name

a = custom_objects_to_plot(10, 20, "a")
b = custom_objects_to_plot(30, 5, "b")
c = custom_objects_to_plot(40, 30, "c")
d = custom_objects_to_plot(120, 10, "d")

def on_pick(event):
    print(event.artist.obj.name)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for obj in [a, b, c, d]:
    artist = ax.plot(obj.x, obj.y, 'ro', picker=5)[0]
    artist.obj = obj

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)

plt.show()
```

Now when you click one of the points on the plot, the name property of the corresponding object will be printed.

Comment: I am getting the following error:     x, y = artist.get_xdata(), artist.get_ydata()
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'get_xdata'

Answer (score 0):

With respect to "a bunch of" in the question, I tested whether picking works with twin axes (no), multiple axes (yes), multiple figures (yes):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots

def on_pick(e):
    print(e.artist.s, e.ind)

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi)

fig, ax = subplots(2)
ax[0].plot(x, np.cos(x), picker=5)[0].s = 'cos'
ax[1].plot(x, np.sin(x), picker=5)[0].s = 'sin'
fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()

fig, ax0 = subplots()
ax0.plot(x, np.tan(x), picker=5)[0].s = 'tan' # Won't work, masked by ax1.
ax0.set_ylim(-3, 3)
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
ax1.plot(x, np.sqrt(x), picker=5)[0].s = 'sqrt'
fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

Example output:

```
cos [6]
sin [32]
sqrt [30]
```