# Remove nodes with mouse click, networkX, python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, networkx, interactive

I have written a program in Python 2.7 with networkX which draws a tree with black and white nodes. Here is a minimal example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

T = nx.Graph()

### Nodes
white, black = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3]
allNodes = white+black

for node in allNodes:      T.add_node(node)

### Edges
T.add_edge(1, 2)
T.add_edge(1, 3)
T.add_edge(2, 4)
T.add_edge(2, 5)
T.add_edge(3, 6)
T.add_edge(3, 7)

### Positions of the nodes
pos={}
pos[1]=numpy.array([ 0,0])
pos[2]=numpy.array([-2,1])
pos[3]=numpy.array([ 2,1])
pos[4]=numpy.array([-3,2])
pos[5]=numpy.array([-1,2])
pos[6]=numpy.array([ 1,2])
pos[7]=numpy.array([ 3,2])

### Draw nodes and edges
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(T, pos, nodelist=black, node_color='k',     node_size=400,     alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(T, pos, nodelist=white, node_color='w',     node_size=400,     alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(T,pos,width=1.0, alpha=0.5)

plt.axis('off')     # Remove the axes
plt.show()          # Show the tree
```

The code creates a window with a small tree containing 7 nodes and 6 edges. Now I     want the nodes to disappear when I click at them with the mouse. How can I do this?

Later my plan is that 2 players alternate in turn by removing leafs or the root in their color (black and white). I.e. player 1 can only remove black leaves or black roots, and player two can only remove white leafs and white roots.

I found these links that could be helpful but couldn't get it to work:

- https://gist.github.com/Zulko/7629965
- https://gist.github.com/smathot/2011427
- [Matplotlib / python clickable points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052532/matplotlib-python-clickable-points)

Anyone who knows how to accomplish this or have some tips?

Comment: I can't help much I'm afraid, but to clarify your question: do you want them to disappear from the plot?  or be deleted from the graph?

Comment: From the plot, they could disappear from the tree also.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do it! I had to save "fig" and "ax" from the plot (I think it is figure and axes?). Then I could connect a method/function, which I call onClick, to the figure which reacts to mouse clicks ('button_press_event').

Here how to get "fig" and "ax" from the plot and connecting the function/method:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
```

And here is the method that removes the nodes from the graph and the plot

```
def onClick(event):
    (x,y)   = (event.xdata, event.ydata)

    for i in allNodes:            
        node = pos[i]
        distance = pow(x-node[0],2)+pow(y-node[1],2)
        if distance < 0.1:
            T.remove_node(i)
            if i in black: black.remove(i)
            if i in white: white.remove(i)
            allNodes.remove(i)
            refreshGraph()
```

The whole code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import numpy as np
import pylab

def refreshGraph():
    plt.clf()
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(T, pos, nodelist=black, node_color='k', node_size=400, alpha=0.8)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(T, pos, nodelist=white, node_color='w', node_size=400, alpha=0.8)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(T,pos,width=1.0, alpha=0.5)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis((-4,4,-1,3))
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
    plt.show()

def onClick(event):
    (x,y)   = (event.xdata, event.ydata)

    for i in allNodes:            
        node = pos[i]
        distance = pow(x-node[0],2)+pow(y-node[1],2)
        if distance < 0.1:
            T.remove_node(i)
            if i in black: black.remove(i)
            if i in white: white.remove(i)
            allNodes.remove(i)
            refreshGraph()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)

T = nx.Graph()

### Nodes
white, black = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3]
allNodes = white+black

for node in allNodes:      T.add_node(node)

### Edges
T.add_edge(1, 2)
T.add_edge(1, 3)
T.add_edge(2, 4)
T.add_edge(2, 5)
T.add_edge(3, 6)
T.add_edge(3, 7)

### Positions of the nodes
pos={}
pos[1]=numpy.array([ 0,0])
pos[2]=numpy.array([-2,1])
pos[3]=numpy.array([ 2,1])
pos[4]=numpy.array([-3,2])
pos[5]=numpy.array([-1,2])
pos[6]=numpy.array([ 1,2])
pos[7]=numpy.array([ 3,2])

### Draw nodes and edges
refreshGraph()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for example how to construct a networkx graph with mouse clicks and was redirected here. So I refactored a code to make it shorter, bug fixed and optimised. I'm using Python 3.8 and Networkx 2.5.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial

def onClick(event, G):
    if event.inaxes is not None and len(G.nodes()) > 0:
        nodelist, coords = zip(*nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos').items())
        kdtree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(coords)
        xy = np.array([event.xdata, event.ydata])
        close_idx = kdtree.query_ball_point(xy, np.sqrt(0.1))
        for i in close_idx:
            G.remove_node(nodelist[i])
        refreshGraph(G)

def refreshGraph(G):
    plt.clf()
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), node_color='k', node_size=400, alpha=0.8)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), width=1.0, alpha=0.5)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis((-4, 4, -1, 3))
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
    plt.show()

#Parameters of graph
nodes = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
edges = np.array([['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'F'], ['C', 'G']])
pos = np.array([[ 0,0], [-2,1], [ 2,1], [-3,2], [-1,2], [ 1,2], [ 3,2]])

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, dict(zip(G.nodes(), pos)), 'pos')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event, G=G: onClick(event, G))
refreshGraph(G)
```

This is a list of things that were improved here:

- `nodes`, `edges` and `pos` can be set in one move using `numpy` arrays.
- no coloring is used in order to make it MWE.
- no global storage of nodes is needed outside graph; `pos` is an attribute of graph itself.
- graph is a parameter of `onClick` and `refreshGraph` hence no global variable is needed to make these functions work
- lookup of close nodes is optimized with a help of [KDtrees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), no lag if there are huge amounts of nodes.
- fixed a bug in calculation of mouse position if a diagram is being clicked outside diagram.
- deletion of multiple nodes within clicked radius is supported.