# Python 2.7 NetworkX (Make it interactive)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, networkx, sna

I am new to NetworkX. Right now, I manage to connect all the nodes to this particular node. What I want to do next it to make it interactive e.g. able to make each of the node move by dragging using cursor. I know I have to make use of matplotlib, but I am not sure how to use it. Can anyone help me?

[image]

My codes are:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import itertools

d = [name of nodes]
f = [number per nodes]

for i in d:
  G.add_edge('"' + i + '"',b)

pos=nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G, k=0.5, iterations=5)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=130, node_color="white")

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos, width=0.2,alpha=1,edge_color='black')

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size=7,font_family='sans-serif')

for i,j in itertools.izip(d,f):
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos, {('"' + i + '"',b):j}, font_size=7, label_pos= 0.80)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Probably a hard thing to do.  Here is one place where I know someone managed to get it to respond to mouse clicks (to delete a node).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289349/remove-nodes-with-mouse-click-networkx-python-2-7?rq=1

Comment: Is there any module other than matplotlib able to do this?

Answer (score 6):

It seems hard to do with matplotlib (it is not really been designed for that). Networkx drawing module is pretty poor it mostly uses a custom scatter plot for nodes, etc.

I suggest another solution:

- Export your graph to JSON or GEXF and use a Javascript graph drawing library to make your graph interactive such as: [SigmaJs](http://sigmajs.org/), or [VivaGraphJs](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS).

You find an example of a real graph created with NetworkX embedded on a webpage on [my blog](http://kirellbenzi.com/blog/hello-montreux-jazz-festival/). Nodes are static in this example but clicking on a node highlights its neighbors.

Official examples for the proposed interactive graph drawing libraries:

- [List of examples using sigma.js](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/examples).
- [Tutorial for VivaGraphJs](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/tree/master/demos/tutorial_svg).

Answer (score 4):

Matplotlib was designed more for static graphs and charts.

However once the NetworkX graph is exported to GEXF format there is a tool which will allow you to select areas based on position or critera in order to move it around.  The tool is called [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io).  You can play with the layout to get started or go as deep as data scientists like to get.

Comment: Tried using Gephi. It is incredible. Thanks! Anyway, is it possible to export the graph in Gephi to web browser using Python 2.7?