# Can a callback be registered with Altair's selection mechanism to interactively change pandas data?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, altair

I'd like to display an altair scatterplot in a jupyter notebook. When a user clicks on a specific point (or, I suppose a range of points), I'd like update the results in another cell. Similar to ipywidgets.

As a more specific example, say I have a dataframe which contains the following columns: `state, county, population, income`

I'm mapping population to the X axis and income to the Y axis. Each dot represents the state (counties are aggregated away).

I'd like to click on a dot (state) and update the results of a data frame where the filter is set to the selected state. So each click will result in the other cell being updated with counties just in that state.

I figured altair would have some sort of callback where I could do this update but I don't see it in the docs.

I also have matplotlib and seaborn available to me, if this can be done with those packages.

I'm in a pretty locked down environment so can't install additional packages (such as plotly).

Comment: Could you add the code that you have so far?

Comment: @YuliaV, unfortunately I can't paste the code. Even this problem is made up, I'm not actually working with states/counties data. The main question really is, how can I use interactive plots to explore my data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052532/matplotlib-python-clickable-points

Answer (score 0):

Altair provides no supported way to dynamically update charts across cells of a Jupyter notebook. It could probably be done in Javascript via the [Vega View API](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/), but I'm not aware of any example of this.